# How to use raw query in join clause in laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using multiple condition in join clause in laravel5 and there is one condition that is passed as a raw condition. How to pass it ?

I am getting this error 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()

Code is

```
->leftjoin('log_simple_calory as LC',
function($join)use($tz_lccreated_date,$dateRange){
  $join->on('LC.user_id_fk','=','UA.user_id_fk');
  $join->on('LC.is_active','=',DB::raw('1'))
  ->whereRaw('date('.$tz_lccreated_date.')'. $dateRange);
})
```

Comment: I guess it could simply be `->where(DB::raw(...))` - no?

Comment: @ArturKäpp , its not working

Answer (score 0):

The `whereRaw` should be outside the `JoinClause` :

```
->leftjoin('log_simple_calory as LC',
function($join)use($tz_lccreated_date,$dateRange){
  $join->on('LC.user_id_fk','=','UA.user_id_fk');
  $join->on('LC.is_active','=',DB::raw('1'))
})->whereRaw('date('.$tz_lccreated_date.')'. $dateRange);
```

Comment: No. Its whereRaw should not be outside in my scenario. its depend on your need. So if you want to use inside join clause then it will not be execute and return an error. in that case we can use subquery.

Comment: The ```where``` clause in a SQL query is always after the join. The thing is that the ```where``` is restricting the entries in the collection, so it definitely  must be outside, since you don't have have a collection in the closure.

Comment: It is not mendatory that where clause is after the join, it depends on join condition, and we can use multiple where condition in join clause when we mapping the foreign key with tables.

Comment: You're talking about the ```on``` clause, not the ```where``` one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 5 and above, this site is very useful, 
for writing raw queries and stuff

[https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries](http://Laravel%20official%20reference)